# Не открывается сбилженый сайт на nextjs, на debian

Tags: debian, nextjs, deploy

Версии
Nextjs: 13.4.7
@next/font: 13.4.7

Билдиться без ошибок, но при попытке открыть страницу идет бесконечное ожидание запроса, тестил на чистом next через CRA. На винде нормально запускается.

Помогло откатиться на версии:
Nextjs: 13.1.6
@next/font: 13.1.6